# My system crashes when I try to enable mod_rewrite module in Wamp Server 2.4

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, crash, wampserver

My system crashes when I try to enable mod_rewrite module in Wamp Server 2.4. Its really frustrating..I reinstalled..then also same problem...I have also installed Visual C++ 2010 SP1 Redistributable Package x86. Then also same issue.

Comment: its a system relented problem

Comment: more appropriate "stack" is http://serverfault.com/